# What does "performant" software actually mean?

Tags: performance, terminology

I see it used a lot, but haven't seen a definition that makes complete sense.

[Wiktionary says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant) "characterized by an adequate or excellent level of performance or efficiency", which isn't much help.

Initially I though performant just meant "fast", but others seem to think it's also about stability, code quality, memory use/footprint, or some combination of all those.

I think this is a "real" question - but if enough people reckon this is a subjective question, that's an answer in itself.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In university, performant means that you have an optimal solution in O(n) notation. You might get a remark on your paper about using made up words instead of the proper terminology though.

In business, performant means that your customer hasn't complained about the speed (yet). Your product is also buzzword compliant.

Comment: so it's a synergistic relationship between fast and cool?  It organically leverages resources by placing the paradigm on speed, evn if the implementation is outside the box?  How would you ballpark it in contrast with non-performant implementations that may have other value-add's?

Comment: +1 for Buzzword Compliance

Answer (score 21):

Performant is a word that was made up by software developers to describe software that performs well, in whatever way you want to define performance.

It's a good word, one that makes sense, based on a different form of an existing word, and one that actually has a valuable purpose.

`<soapbox>`

Contrast that with the phrase, "begging the question," which has been used incorrectly for so long that it may actually be recognized soon in its incorrect form as common usage "correct" English.

`</soapbox>`

Comment: It's taken from French... in French, "performant" means efficient.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant from French. And acceptable now. Easier on some tongues than saying "My app's performance is ..."

Comment: Or whatever way you want not to define performance. Waving your hands may suffice though.

Answer (score 6):

> What does “performant” software actually mean?

Nothing. Everything. Whatever you want. Whatever the other guy in the discussion wants (which is usually the opposite of yours).

> I [...] haven't seen a definition that makes complete sense.

Exactly.

It's a great ignition source for flamewars, that's about all it's useful for.

Exception: **if** you have a *precise* definition **and** *everybody* agrees on that definition **and** that definition is in place *before* the argument starts, then and *only* then can you have a meaningful discussion / argument.

[BTW: it's the same for "scalable" and "strongly typed", among others.]

Comment: I like this answer - performant has infinite definitions depending on the context upon which it is used in. Specifically, the organizations needs/workflow. 

For instance, WordPress, while being extremely "performant" for marketing, blogs, business websites, etc.. it isn't "performant" if the organization has a highly customized backend like custom forms that have exports and reporting. In those cases, I feel that the CMS becomes overhead.

Answer (score 5):

The lay-person's definition is simple: "something that's performant performs well; performant == high performance, !performant == low performance"

I don't see it being applied to measures other than performance.  Ugly, hackish, and unstable code can be performant.

Comment: OK, but is "performance" just speed, or something else?

Comment: I think at the root of it performance does just mean speed.  I could see "performance" being related to overall resource usage, but to me the bottom line is it's a measurement against time.

Comment: I would say PERFORMANCE = SPEED + ACCURACY (both within an acceptable margin). If the product is failing, it's not really performing, even if it fails quickly.

Comment: @STW I think performance is very neutral and more relates to say `a music performance` where the music is performed and there is a performance as a result. Also, performing well or performing badly can be subjective where as performant (imo) is performing optimally in all regards.

Comment: Only when performance is a function of speed. The details of what makes up performance can be variable - possibly speed, possibly algorithmic simplicity, possibly the frequency with which your bowling algorithm results in strikes. Or perfect games. Or simply wins.

Comment: @msg45f very good point!  Know your domain, engineer accordingly :-)

Comment: Unlike speed, performance cannot be quantified. There are units of speed. There are no units of performance. Something can be 10% faster but not 10% more performant. If performance is a function of speed, then that function is implicitly a black box. If something is performant it is more gooder in an unknown or complex way the speaker doesn't know or understand but feels the need to impress upon the listener despite this inherent ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Having a performant product means that you have successfully become buzzword-compliant. Further, you may now consider that product to be approved by Marketing Weasels.